# Obtener valores de un select múltiple (Materialize)

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

mi problema es que no puedo o no se cómo obtener los valores de un ***select mútiple*** de ***Materialize*** `V 0.100.2`, si alguien pudiera explicarme o ayudarme, por favor, llevo esto, pero ***no me retorna nada!!***:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  $("select").material_select();

  $(".jsBtnSaveValuesNotificationsShedule").on("click", () => {

    console.log($(".jsSelectedSchedule").val());

  });

});
```

```html
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <select class="jsSelectedSchedule" name="jsNameSelectedSchedule" multiple>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione</option>
      <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
      <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
    </select>
    <label>Selecciona el tipo de horario</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col m4 offset-m4 s4 offset-s4">
    <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light jsBtnSaveValuesNotificationsShedule">Obtener
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logré solucionar el problema, lo que hice fue cambiar la forma en la que accedo al elemento select, es decir, obtuve el los valores por el `name` en lugar de acceder a él por la `clase`, es decir: `$('select[name^="jsNameSelectedSchedule"]').val()` dejo la solución por si alguién presenta este inconveniente en el futuro:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("select").material_select();
  $(".jsBtnSaveValuesNotificationsShedule").on("click", () => {
    console.log($('select[name^="jsNameSelectedSchedule"]').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <select class="jsSelectedSchedule" name="jsNameSelectedSchedule" multiple>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione</option>
      <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
      <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
    </select>
    <label>Selecciona el tipo de horario</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col m4 offset-m4 s4 offset-s4">
    <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light jsBtnSaveValuesNotificationsShedule">Obtener</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El atributo "name" del select debe finalizar con "[]".
De esta manera:

```
<select class="jsSelectedSchedule" name="jsNameSelectedSchedule[]" multiple>
  <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Que tal Alan, gracias por la respuesta, lo intenté, pero no me sirvió, siempre me devuelve unas comillas dobles en el console.log(). Qué crees que pueda ser?